# JSON: fix messed up JSON string

Tags: php, mysql, json

as usual I'm working with my messed up database and I found that there are some fuxked up JSON string in the database... Some of the JSON strings are missing the double-quotes around the keys and/or values.

I'm thinking of writing a PHP script to fix that, what recommendations do you guys have about how I can detect the missing quotes and automatically add them? Or there is no such convenient way...

Thanks smart community!

Comment: [PEARs JSON class](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON) can parse such Javascript expressions, as can upgradephp; though not for values. Conversion approaches have been covered in previous questions on that very topic.

Comment: @mario Thank you for the information, but does it handle this kind of missing quotes situation? Problem is that some of the JSON strings are not well formed... Anyways I will do a search on other similar questions and see what I find...

Comment: Yes, it does handle missing key quotes. But no, completely garbled JSON cannot be reconstructed. You would need a resilent regex for that. (= No. Too much effort.)

Comment: @mario Hmm that sounds very interesting... I'm curious in how it can handle the missing quotes if the JSON objects are nested... I have already fixed my problem through a very specific detection mechanism, since the error cases are contained. Thank you for your knowledge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json_decode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [json_last_error](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to detect if there is an error in the string. And then [json_encode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to write the valid json value back out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I don't see how the json_last_error would help me though. I know there will be an error, but fixing it is the main issue.

Comment: Well I have already fixed the problem, luckily the number of error cases is contained so I can just do a very specific detection... Thanks for your reply, and I'll accept your answer to appreciate your help :)